# url images, 301 redirection

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to add a 301 redirection in my htaccess file.

This redirection should redirect the here below url :

www.Site.com/785-7431-large/item_name.jpg

towards this here after url :

www.Site.com/7431-large/item_name.jpg

The data 785 and 7431 are just examples.

The data "785" could actually goes from 01 to 9999
The data "7461" could actually goes from 1000 to 99999

**Would anyone know what should be the code to add in the htaccess file to make this 301 redirection ?**

Thank you very much in advance for any help in this matter

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\d+-(\d+-large/.+)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```